# Server performance question about streaming from cosmos dB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I read the article [here](https://anthonychu.ca/post/async-streams-dotnet-core-3-iasyncenumerable/) about IAsyncEnumerable, more specifically towards a Cosmos Db-datasource

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<T> Get<T>(string containerName, string sqlQuery)
{
    var container = GetContainer(containerName);
    using FeedIterator<T> iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(sqlQuery);

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var item in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    } 
}
```

I am wondering how the CosmosDB is handling this, compared to paging, lets say 100 documents at the time. We have had some "429 - Request rate too large"-errors in the past and I dont wish to create new ones.

So, how will this affect server load/performance.
I dont see a big difference **from the servers perspective**, between when client is streaming (and doing some quick checks), and old way, get all document and `while (iterator.HasMoreResults)` and collect the items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK will retrieve batches of documents that can be adjusted in size using the `QueryRequestOptions` and changing the `MaxItemCount` (which defaults to 100 if not set). It has no option though to throttle the RU usage apart from it running into the `429` error and using the retry mechanism the SDK offers to retry a while later. Depending on how generous you set the retry mechanism it'll retry oft & long enough to get a proper response.

If you have a situation where you want to limit the RU usage for e.g. there's multiple processes using your cosmos and you don't want those to result in `429` errors you would have to write the logic yourself.

An example of how something like that could look:

```cs
var qry = container
    .GetItemLinqQueryable<Item>(requestOptions: new() { MaxItemCount = 2000 })
    .ToFeedIterator();

var results = new List<Item>();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
var targetRuMsRate = 200d / 1000; //target 200RU/s
var previousElapsed = 0L;
var delay = 0;
stopwatch.Start();
var totalCharge = 0d;

while (qry.HasMoreResults)
{
    if (delay > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
    previousElapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var response = await qry.ReadNextAsync();
    var charge = response.RequestCharge;
    var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var delta = elapsed - previousElapsed;
    delay = (int) ((charge - targetRuMsRate * delta) / targetRuMsRate);

    foreach (var item in response)
    {
        results.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Internally the SDK will call the underlying Cosmos REST API. Once your code reaches the `iterator.ReadNextSync()` it will call the [query documents method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents) in the background. If you would dig into the source code or intercept the message send to `HttpClient` you can observe the resulting message which lacks the `x-ms-max-item-count` header that determines the number of the documents it'll try to retrieve (unless you have specified a `MaxItemCount` yourself). According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api) it'll default to 100 if not set:

> Query requests support pagination through the x-ms-max-item-count and x-ms-continuation request headers. The x-ms-max-item-count header specifies the maximum number of values that can be returned by the query execution. This can be between 1 and 1000, and is configured with a default of 100.

Comment: Ok...so  if the SDK is paging the data anyway, internally, the option 1 and 2 (in  my question) is that given the page size is 100 (or same in both option) the server will not see any difference, correct? Do you have  any link/source for the internal behavior?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by option 1 and 2 as I only see 1 code example in your question (which retrieves them in bulk yes). Added some explanation in the question regarding source info.

Comment: Option 2 would be to get all documents and and collect them in a 
while(iterator.HasMoreResults)-loop

Comment: @Cowborg The SDK will always get them in batches if you perform a query. The only thing the article you linked mentions is how you can avoid materializing them into memory and instead yield them as needed. Aslong as you iterate over the resulting collection it doesn't matter on the Cosmos server side and will result in the same overall RU usage. As you're code will always call `iterator.ReadNextAsync()` which will always retrieve the next batch with the same RU usage.

Comment: Ok, so no difference then (for the server). If you want to "complete" the question and get som SO-credits, you can copy that into an answer and Ill set it to the correct answer. Thanks!